# Player crashes in application

Tags: windows-phone-7

all. I am trying to develop an application for Windows Phone 7 using Visual Studio 2010. It is a music player that is supposed to be able to play music based on the current event.

I managed to extract the event but when I tried to combine it with the player, the entire player would just crash. Here are the codes.

```
void Appointments_SearchCompleted(object sender, AppointmentsSearchEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            AppointmentResultsDataLINQ.DataContext =
                from Appointment appt in e.Results
                where appt.IsAllDayEvent == false                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                select appt;       

        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            //No results
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if ((((Appointment)(AppointmentResultsDataLINQ.DataContext)).Subject).Equals("Meeting"))
        {
             mediaElement1.Source = new Uri("http://www.opendrive.com/files/NV8zNTMwNDYwX2hxRXZR/Crystallize.mp3", UriKind.Absolute);              
        }          

        else
        {
            mediaElement1.Source = new Uri("https://www.opendrive.com/files/NV8zMjAxODY0X0VBNDJY/Hetken%20tie%20on%20kevyt%20(piano%20cover)%20-%20YouTube.mp3", UriKind.Absolute);                
        }
            mediaElement1.Play();
    }
```

Comment: what is the runtime exception do you get?

Comment: How do you check it? I'm sorry but I'm still very new in C# and windows phone programming.

Comment: how does it crash? what messages do you get?

Comment: When I clicked the button to start the player, the entire application just quit by itself. No messages being shown.

Comment: is this on the device or the simulator?

Comment: The device. I tried clicking the player on the simulator and I got these.

http://img10.imageshack.us/img10/2392/code1e.png

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the cast. You are trying to cast the `AppointmentResultsDataLINQ.DataContext` to an `Appointment`. This does not make sense. You need to select one concrete appointment from using LINQ (similar to the code in your `Appointments_SearchCompleted` that imho does nothing)

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite get it. Which part should I modify?